# putting inputs in array c program

Tags: c

There exist two numbers `x` and `y` such that  `x! + y! = 10!` And a method named `solve10`  that returns the values `x` and `y` in an array( `a[0] == x, a[1] == y and x! + y! = 10!`)
my code

```
int * solve10()
{
    int fact=1;
    printf("Enter two elements");
    scanf("%d",&x,&y);
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        intx1=fact*i;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<y;i++){
       inty1=fact*i; 
    }
    //check condition
    if(x1+y1=10!){
        //how to retrun x in a[0] ie a[0]=x and a[1]=y
        int a[][]={x,y}
    }
}
```

How can i solve this please give me hint

Comment: what is `x! + y! = 10! `?

Comment: @Sourav OP is obviously trying to find `x` and `y` that satisfy the equation.  But the code is seriously broken and incomplete.

Comment: Where are the declaration of x1, y1, x, y, intx1 and inty1?

Comment: I did a quick check, and I don't believe there are any non-negative integers `x` and `y` that satisfy `x! + y! == 10!`, so don't get your hopes up for this.

Comment: Here's a simple proof that there's no solution:  Clearly `x` and `y` must both be less than 10.  The largest possible sum of `x!` and `y!` is therefore when `x = y = 9`, so `9! + 9!` which is `2*9!`.  But `10!` is just `10*9!`, which is clearly larger.  Therefore, there are no such `x` and `y`.  QED.

Comment: The only solution to `x! + y! = z!` (where `x` and `y` are natural numbers) is `1! + 1! = 2!`.

Comment: @user3386109 Don't forget `0! + 0! = 2! `and `0! + 1! = 2!`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use nested loop.

```
int p = fact(10);
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
   for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++){
       if(fact(i) + fact(j) == p){
         a[0] = i;
         a[1] = j;
         return a;
      }
  }
}
```

You can implement fact function which will be used to calculate the factorial of an integer .

Answer (score 0):

You can return a pointer like you wanted :

```
int * solve10(){
    //your code assigning x and y
    int * returnValue = malloc(2 * sizeof (int));
    returnValue[0]=x;
    returnValue[1]=y;
    return returnValue;
}
```